# Mac M1 get IOMobileFramebufferUserClient interface

Tags: swift, macos, iokit

I am trying to get access to framebuffer interface for a M1 Mac. I know it's quite different from other Mac, because these new Mac use IOMobileFrameBuffer (which comes from OS) instead of classical IOFrameBuffer.

So I tried to use this code to access this framebuffer with no luck.

```
func makeIterator() -> io_iterator_t {
    var port: mach_port_t = 0
    var status = IOMasterPort(mach_port_t(MACH_PORT_NULL), &port)
    guard status == KERN_SUCCESS else { return 0 }
    guard let match = IOBSDNameMatching(port, 0, "AppleMobileCLCD") else { return 0 }
    var iterator: io_iterator_t = 0
    status = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(port, match, &iterator)
    guard status == KERN_SUCCESS else { return 0 }
    return iterator
}
```

I also tried with "IOMobileFramebuffer", "AppleCLCD" and "IOMobileFramebufferUserClient" strings but the matching does not seem to be ok.

I tried also to display ioreg command which told me:

> +-o IOMobileFramebufferUserClient  <class IOMobileFramebufferUserClient, id 0x1000007fb, !registered, !matched,
> active, busy 0, retain 5>

Do you know how I can find the string to access this user client ?
Or maybe I am totally wrong with this code...
I am trying to search for setting up some luminosity in this interface. I think it won't work well, but I want to try...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason your matching (`IOServiceGetMatchingServices`) call is not returning the object you're looking for is because your matching dictionary is incorrect.

First of all, let's look at the `ioreg` output (command line: `ioreg -w0 -irc IOMobileFramebuffer`) for the objects you're interested in. On my Mac Mini, they look like this:

```
+-o AppleCLCD2  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOMobileFramebuffer:IOMobileFramebufferService:IOMobileFramebufferAP:UnifiedPipeline2:AppleCLCD2, id 0x100000300, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 15>
[…]
+-o AppleCLCD2  <class IORegistryEntry:IOService:IOMobileFramebuffer:IOMobileFramebufferService:IOMobileFramebufferAP:UnifiedPipeline2:AppleCLCD2, id 0x1000002bc, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 14>
```

First of all, `IOBSDNameMatching` is for matching devices which have equivalents in the BSD subsystem (essentially, they appear under `/dev/`) which is only the case a few kinds of device on macOS, for example block storage devices and serial ports. (If it *was* the correct function for this purpose, you would also need to pass `kIOMasterPortDefault` as the first argument as the documentation instructs.)

I'm not sure where you're getting `"AppleMobileCLCD"` from, perhaps that's the entry's *name* on your system (instead of `AppleCLCD2` on the Mac Mini).

If that's the case, you need to use [`IOServiceNameMatching`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1514416-ioservicenamematching?language=objc) to create the matching dictionary.

However, matching by name is usually not a great idea unless you have a very good reason; instead, match by class name, using [`IOServiceMatching()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/iokit/1514687-ioservicematching?language=objc). So, for example:

```
    guard let match = IOServiceMatching("IOMobileFramebuffer") else { return 0 }
```

This should work.

You will usually not be able to match existing *user client* objects, such as the one whose `ioreg` line you quote, as they are typically not registered for matching. (they show as `!registered`) They generally also don't have any usable interface, as they *are* the interface for their provider object.

There is no documented interface for `IOMobileFramebuffer` but perhaps you can find something useful to do with it nevertheless.

Comment: Perfect! Works great !